# Convert XML text to "UPPER CASE" using php

Tags: php

I create a form where user can see the client information through database.And user can download the client information through the database which is **.xls** file.

The problem was, is there a way where when user download the .xls file and the information in .xls file will change to UPPERCASE?

Comment: Also, can you show us how the .xls file is being generated?

Answer (score 0):

You can parse the .xls file then you can apply strtoupper for required fields and finally you can output as an .xls file to your user.

Comment: "parse the .xls file then you can apply strtoupper for required fields"

Can explain in more detail? I quite not understand :)

Comment: If your .xls file is a static file (not generated by PHP on the fly, if so change the case at the time of .xls file creation.) You need to parse the .xls file using PHP, apply the change case for required columns then recreate the .xls file.

Comment: is generated by php :-

function xlsBOF() {
echo pack("ssssss", 0x809, 0x8, 0x0, 0x10, 0x0, 0x0);
return;
}
function xlsEOF() {
echo pack("ss", 0x0A, 0x00);
return;
}
function xlsWriteNumber($Row, $Col, $Value) {
echo pack("sssss", 0x203, 14, $Row, $Col, 0x0);
echo pack("d", $Value);
return;
}
function xlsWriteLabel($Row, $Col, $Value ) {
$L = strlen($Value);
echo pack("ssssss", 0x204, 8 + $L, $Row, $Col, 0x0, $L);
echo $Value;
return;
}